# I define my variables, but I still get 'Error: Cannot find symbol'

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project for my "Java I" course that deals with image filters and mirrors. I am trying to create a horizontal mirror effect (the vertical mirror is hardcoded into java I believe), but when I try running my code I get the message:

> Error: Symbol cannot be found

for the the line I marked with a comment. I've been getting this error alot recently (in other programs I am working on), so I am sure that I must be making the same mistake. If someone could help me fix this, it would help me unravel a whole world of compiling errors.

```
public static void testMirrorHorizontal()
{
    Picture gorge = new Picture("gorge.jpg");
    Pixel[][] pixels = gorge.getPixels2D();
    Pixel topPixel = null;
    Pixel bottomPixel = null;
    int width = gorge.getWidth();
    int length = pixels[0].width; //  I'm getting the error here
    for (int col = 0; col < pixels.length; col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < height / 2; row++)
        {
            topPixel = pixels[row][col];
            bottomPixel = pixels[col][height - 1 - row];
            bottomPixel.setColor(bottomPixel.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite strange that you only get *"Symbol cannot be found"* and no information about _which_ symbol couldn't be found ...

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
int length = pixels[0].width;
```

to

```
int length = pixels[0].length;
```

`pixels[index]` has no `width` property.

By using `pixels[0].length`, you get the number of pixels contained within the **first** row of pixels in your 2-D array of pixels.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags to the question just to earn the "Refiner" badge.

Comment: That was **totally** not my intention. I thought it had something to do with *Swing* or *AWT*, since he's manipulating pixels & their colors.

Comment: Since his problem is the wrong usage of his array, `Swing` is not necessary to answer the question. It would be related if he has a problem with the UI itself, like problems during paint or other stuff. So an "array" tag (or a 2d-array tag) would be related. Btw: if this badge really wasn't your intention, then sorry for the accusation.

Comment: You're right concerning the tag choice. I just thought that there was something odd with the code's logic, so adding the *Swing* tag would probably get more attention to the question..

Comment: In that case it might be better to suggest OP to ask for a code review on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ when his code works correctly. Or if he still has a problem with his code concerning the logic, then he should ask a new question about this.

Comment: Thanks for the site suggestion ! Never knew that it existed.. (Waiting for the OP)

Comment: If you click on the StackExchange logo on the top dark grey bar, then you can see all sites of the Stack Exchange network ... and there are a lot of them :D.